# Swipe on Oculus GO Touchpad triggers UI clicks when it shouldn't

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Using:
Unity 2018.4.1 LTS &
Oculus GO

I am using a gaze pointer to interact with Unity UI.

This is supposed to happen when you pull the trigger, exactly how I defined it in my script: a swipe left or right on the touchpad of the go-controller however triggers clicks as well. I did not define this myself, it's just a thing that happens and I can not figure out how to work around it.

I found and fiddled around with solutions proposed in [this thread](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/64969/oculus-go-touchpad-swipe-detected-as-getmousebuttondown-0-in-unity) and [this thread](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/comment/519102#Comment_519102).

However, none of these solutions provided me a way to get rid of these swipe clicks while keeping alive index trigger clicks.

My Input Manager (Index Trigger Interaction with UI seems to happen in OVRInputModule):

```
 private void Update()
        {

            if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryTouchpad) || OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.Two))
            {
                ToggleVidInterface();

            }

            if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger))
            {
                StartCoroutine(TouchpadCounter()); 
            }

        }

        IEnumerator TouchpadCounter()
        {
            int secondsForCounting = 2;
            float startTime = Time.time;
            int touchCount = 0;

            while (Time.time - startTime <= secondsForCounting && OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger))
            {
                if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryTouchpad))
                {
                    touchCount++;
                    Debug.Log("touchCount for Admin Menue: " + touchCount);
                }

                if (touchCount >= 3)
                {
                    ActivateAdminMenue();
                }

                yield return null;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
```

Part of the OVRInputModule (I don't know if its the right part):

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Get state of button corresponding to gaze pointer
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        virtual protected PointerEventData.FramePressState GetGazeButtonState()
        {
            var pressed = Input.GetKeyDown(gazeClickKey) || OVRInput.GetDown(joyPadClickButton);
            var released = Input.GetKeyUp(gazeClickKey) || OVRInput.GetUp(joyPadClickButton);



#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
            // On Gear VR the mouse button events correspond to touch pad events. We only use these as gaze pointer clicks
            // on Gear VR because on PC the mouse clicks are used for actual mouse pointer interactions.
            pressed |= Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
            released |= Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0);
#endif



            if (pressed && released)
                return PointerEventData.FramePressState.PressedAndReleased;
            if (pressed)
                return PointerEventData.FramePressState.Pressed;
            if (released)
                return PointerEventData.FramePressState.Released;
            return PointerEventData.FramePressState.NotChanged;
        }
```

Messing with the Android if condition just enables or disables clicking as a whole (trigger and touchpad). What am I missing here? How can I seperate between a trigger click and a touchpad swipe?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it out:

katbot's answer is one of two parts to separate Trigger Click from Touchpad swipe Click.

First comment out in `OVRInputModule.cs` like so:

```
virtual protected PointerEventData.FramePressState GetGazeButtonState()
{
    var pressed = Input.GetKeyDown(gazeClickKey) || OVRInput.GetDown(joyPadClickButton);
    var released = Input.GetKeyUp(gazeClickKey) || OVRInput.GetUp(joyPadClickButton);

    //  Comment out or remove this block, because it causes touchpad touch events to register as click events.
// #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    // On Gear VR the mouse button events correspond to touch pad events. We only use these as gaze pointer clicks
    // on Gear VR because on PC the mouse clicks are used for actual mouse pointer interactions.
    //pressed |= Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
    //released |= Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0);
// #endif

    if (pressed && released)
            return PointerEventData.FramePressState.PressedAndReleased;
    if (pressed)
            return PointerEventData.FramePressState.Pressed;
    if (released)
            return PointerEventData.FramePressState.Released;
    return PointerEventData.FramePressState.NotChanged;
}
```

THEN go to your `OVRInputModule` in UnityEditor. Under "**Joy Pad Click Button**" now choose "**Primary Index Trigger**". Now you have killed the touchpad swipe click by commenting out the `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` stuff, which kills normal Trigger Clicks as well. But we can bring them back by linking them to the "Joy Pad Click Button" in Unity Editor.

Answer (score 2):

I too ran into this issue, and I resolved it by commenting out part of OVRInputModule.GetGazeButtonState() like this:

```
        virtual protected PointerEventData.FramePressState GetGazeButtonState()
        {
            var pressed = Input.GetKeyDown(gazeClickKey) || OVRInput.GetDown(joyPadClickButton);
            var released = Input.GetKeyUp(gazeClickKey) || OVRInput.GetUp(joyPadClickButton);

//  Comment out or remove this block, because it causes touchpad touch events to register as click events.
// #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
//             // On Gear VR the mouse button events correspond to touch pad events. We only use these as gaze pointer clicks
//             // on Gear VR because on PC the mouse clicks are used for actual mouse pointer interactions.
//             pressed |= Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
//             released |= Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0);
// #endif

            if (pressed && released)
                return PointerEventData.FramePressState.PressedAndReleased;
            if (pressed)
                return PointerEventData.FramePressState.Pressed;
            if (released)
                return PointerEventData.FramePressState.Released;
            return PointerEventData.FramePressState.NotChanged;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I already did this and you are right about it disabling the touchpad swipe click, however it deactivates index finger click as well and I need this to stay functional. So what I'm looking for is a way to seperate touchpad swipe and trigger click from each other.